# leer archivo de texto por siempre

Tags: php, script, perl

hace un tiempo hice la consulta de script como proceso permantente. Finalmente no logre solucionar eso pero resolvi el inconveniente de otra manera. Actualmente estoy buscando la opcion de que un script vaya leyendo la informacion de un archivo de texto o .csv y que por cada registro que se agregue vaya realizando una accion.
Con Perl existe la opcion OPEN y mediante el bucle puedo no cerrar el archivo y dejar a perl leyendo dicho fichero por siempre, pero con PHP no consigo forma de hacerlo.
El ejemplo es muy sencillo

```
<?php
//abrimos el archivo en lectura
$archivo = 'test.txt';
$fp = fopen($archivo,'r');
//leemos el archivo
$texto = fread($fp, filesize($archivo));
$texto = nl2br($texto);
echo $texto;
?>
```

Con esto abro el archivo, y si se fijan no hago un fclose, pero igualmente PHP al encontrar la ultima linea, simplemente se detiene.
Mi idea es que no se detenga, si no hay mas lineas, que quede esperando a que se pueda insertar otro registro en el archivo test.txt.
Espero se entienda y gracias de antemano.
Saludos!

Comment: No esta claro el contexto del Script que en este caso puede ser relevante. Vista la pregunta creo que lo más óptimo seria crear un cron job que ejecute el Script cada cierto tiempo.

Comment: Es un proceso para asterisk.En asterisk para crear llamadas desatendidas se puede crear un archivo.call en un formato predefinido y pegarlo en una carpeta preestablecida.
Al hacer esto, la llamada (cada archivo) se procesa y se ejecuta.

Mi idea es generar "X" archivos como "X" numeros posea dentro de una base de datos. El problema es que copiar todos los archivos a la vez, hara que se generen todas esas llamadas al mismo tiempo, y mi idea es que vaya en orden, es decir,
Un archivo = primera llamada; Termina la primera llamada
copia el segundo archivo = Segunda llamada

Comment: Todo se saca de una Base de datos

Answer (score 0):

En Perl se suele usar el módulo **[File::Tail](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Tail)** (**[o alguna de sus variantes](https://metacpan.org/search?q=File%3A%3ATail)**) para realizar esa tarea de forma cómoda. Seguro que en PHP hay una solución similar. **[Por ejemplo](https://www.devdungeon.com/content/how-tail-file-php)**.

Comment: Gracias! con el dato que me diste de Perl encontre algo para PHP
     <?php
     $handle = popen("tail -f /etc/httpd/logs/access.log 2>&1", 'r');
      while(!feof($handle)) {
      $buffer = fgets($handle);
       echo "$buffer<br/>\n";
       ob_flush();
        flush();
     }
     pclose($handle);